# How to splice an element to the start of an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to create a function that rotates the array depending on how many times num is === to. So if `num = 2` `["Harry", "Sarah", "Oscar", "Tina"]` becomes `["Oscar", "Tina", "Harry", "Sarah"]`

Here is my code so far:

```
var count = 0;

function rotate(arr, num) {
  while (count < num) {
    arr.splice(0,0, "Tina");
    arr.pop();
    count++
  }
  return arr
}

console.log(rotate(["Harry", "Sarah", "Oscar", "Tina"], 2));
```

For this Line -  `arr.splice(0,0, "Tina")`; I want it to be so that it will bring whatever name is the fourth element to the front of the array, I'm not sure if this is possible? I am suppposed to do this method using splice. Thanks for any help?! :)

Edit: This question is different to other questions. I don't want a full blown solution for rotation, I just want to know if it's possible to splice the fourth element to the beginning?

Comment: Eerily similar to [Javascript rotating an array using a function with splice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29775123/710446) but the mistakes in the code here are distinct from the mistakes in the other question.

Comment: *" I just want to know if it's possible to splice the fourth element to the beginning?"* Pretty simple: `arr.unshift(arr.pop())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shifting the array in a `for` loop:

```js
function rotate(arr, num){
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        item = arr[arr.length-1]
        arr.splice(arr.length-1, 1);
        arr.unshift(item)
    }
    return arr
}

alert(JSON.stringify(rotate(["Harry", "Sarah", "Oscar", "Tina"], 2)));
alert(JSON.stringify(rotate(["Harry", "Sarah", "Oscar", "Tina"], 1)));
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct implementation, it just coincidentally produces the expected result for `2`. But for `1`, it produces `Sarah,Oscar,Tina,Harry`, instead of `Tina, Harry, Sarah, Oscar` -- which seems what the OP really wants, according to my interpretation of *"I want it to be so that it will bring whatever name is the fourth element to the front of the array,"*

Comment: @FelixKling ah, my code was switched I guess, let me edit.

Comment: (Then again, the OP's question is not 100% clear to me)

Comment: @FelixKling, fixed, I wasn't sure either, but I hope this is correct now :)

Comment: Yeah, when I was testing it out I noticed that, the updated version is exactly what I was trying to do, I was unaware of unshift, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. First splice the last `num` elements off the end of the array, then splice them all onto the front.

```js
function rotate(arr, num) {
        var lastN = arr.splice(-num, num);
        [].splice.apply(arr, [0, 0].concat(lastN));
        return arr;
    }
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rotate(["Harry", "Sarah", "Oscar", "Tina"], 2));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```